# multiple WHERE entries in one php query from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display entries in one table from my 'shop' database WHERE fragrance is lager & pilsner.

So far I have only able to get either-or to be displayed:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * from shop WHERE fragrance='Lager'";

//generate SQL query
$result1=$dbh->prepare($query1);

//execute query
$result1->execute();

echo '<table id="tab1">';
 while($row=$result1->fetch()){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['type'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['fragrance'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

How do I search for both in one query? any help would be amazing!

Comment: *WHERE fragrance is lager & pilsner* do you mean it contains both values or either of the values?

Comment: both fragrances @NigelRen

Comment: There is still some uncertainty about what you need from this query. I suggest you show example data for a shop that you want the query to return, and an example of a shop that you _don't_ want the query to return, and explain why.

Comment: If the field for `fragrance` is a `varchar` etc.. the query could only ever be satisfied with `OR`. Unless unless OP uses something like `Lager;Pilsner;Sweet`, and we're hacking it with `LIKE %`, I hope not.  Only if it is a `SET` field, could  an `AND` condition be satisfied .

Comment: I don't want it to display any other fragrance other than 'lager' or 'pilsner'. The answer using an OR operator by @scaisEdge worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  an OR operator

```
"SELECT * from shop WHERE fragrance='Lager' OR fragrance='Pilsner'
```

Comment: That, or `WHERE fragrance IN ('Lager', 'Pilsner')` to keep it shorter.